# Secure mail importation in Gmail (plaintext and ssl configuration)

Tags: ssl, gmail, mail-server, plaintext, dovecot

I've set up my mail server by using postfix (mysql), dovecot, and applied a ssl certificate to *mail.example.com* with Let's encrypte.

I tried to get my mail with Gmail by importing the account *user@domaine.tld*, I couldn't do it with the SSL box checked, so I unchecked, and still got an error because of plaintext authentication.

*[AUTH] Plaintext authentication disallowed on non-secure (SSL/TLS) connections.*

So I modified :
`/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf` with `disable_plaintext_auth = no`

and
`/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf` with `ssl = required`

I successfully get the mail in Gmail, but my question is : Is it secured ? 
I'm not sure to understand this :

> `ssl=yes` and `disable_plaintext_auth=no`: SSL/TLS is offered to the client, but the client isn't required to use it. The client is allowed to login with plaintext authentication even when SSL/TLS isn't enabled on the connection. This is insecure, because the plaintext password is exposed to the internet.

Is the password transmitted encrypted (because of the SSL configuration) or not (because of the plaintext configuration).

(From : https://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration)

If not, how can I secure it ? Or make it works properly to me and Gmail.

Thanks a lot

Comment: My mail.log with/without the SSL checkbox :

`Dec 26 12:48:37 smtp dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (tried to use disallowed plaintext auth): user=<>, rip=209.85.xxx.xxx, lip=163.172.xxx.xxx, session=<FIoVaet9NwDRVdCQ>`
`Dec 26 12:50:41 smtp dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=209.85.xxx.xxx , lip=163.172.xxx.xxx, session=<M+d1cOt9TgDRVacf>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your password is not transmitted unencrypted. It is, as you suspect, protected by the TLS encryption. The `ssl = required` enforces the use of TLS. The `disable_plaintext_auth=no`allows the authentication to send the password as is, *inside*, the encrypted connection. This is the defacto standard for most mail servers.

I would recommend using IMAP instead of POP3, if that is feasible for you.

Comment: Thanks ! POP3 is required by gmail.